# Failed to find method - AWS .NET Core 3.1 Mock Lambda Test Tool

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1

I am trying use/setup the AWS .NET Core 3.1 Mock Lambda Test Tool.

Currently I am going to launch the application via the tool, however, once I try and send a request I receive the error "Failed to find method Init".

Inside the `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` I setting the `function-handler` to the following:

```js
"function-handler": "Some.Example.Assembly::Some.Example.Namespace.LambdaProgram::Init"
```

The LambdaProgram.cs file looks like the following:

```cs
using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Some.Example.Namespace
{
    public class LambdaProgram : APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

The format seems correct to me unless I am misreading the documentation?

Inside the `bin/` directory the dll and exe have the matching names, i.e. "Some.Example.Assembly.exe" & "Some.Example.Assembly.dll".

If I change the `function-handler` path then I can make it throw an error for the type. But I do not understand why it cannot find the function Init? The application builds and the `LambdaProgram` is implementing the AWS interface as required.

Any help would be amazing, I really want to be able to test/debug locally before deploying (This is an existing application in production - this is just a case of lamabda migration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After being utterly confused for hours, I have found the solution. This may be in the documentation and I failed to see it but the `function-handler` is NOT the function inside the LambdaProgram class (or whatever you called yours).

Rather you should be using `FunctionHandlerAsync` which I guess is being inherited.

I found this by cloning the [official repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool) and looking at their samples, in there is a comment detailing this!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace BlueprintBaseName._1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class extends from APIGatewayProxyFunction which contains the method FunctionHandlerAsync which is the 
    /// actual Lambda function entry point. The Lambda handler field should be set to
    /// 
    /// BlueprintBaseName.1::BlueprintBaseName.1.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
    /// </summary>
    public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction

        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```